# How to use "Select()" within a subquery function in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I may not be using the right phrasing, but my issue is this:

I have this query

```php
$result = Table_one_model::with(['Table_two' => function($query) use ($thing_id) {
    $query->where('thing_id', $thing_id);
}])
->select('col_one', 'col_two')
->get();
```

I'd like to add one more thing to the select from table_two, however if I add it to the existing select above like `select('col_one', 'col_two', 'col_from_other_table')` it doesn't work, and if I add the select into the table_two query like below it also doesn't work:

```php
$result = Table_one_model::with(['Table_two' => function($query) use ($thing_id) {
    $query->where('thing_id', $thing_id)->select('col_from_other_table');
}])
->select('col_one', 'col_two')
->get();
```

In both of these cases, I get results but the results from `table_two` just show as 'null'

Without the second table select I get this result:

```
{
  "col_one": 0,
  "col_two": 0,
  "table_one": {
    "id":1,
    "blah":0,
    "col_from_other_table":0
    ...all the contents of table two
  }
}
```

With the select within the table_two query I get this:

```
{
  "col_one": 0,
  "col_two": 0,
  "table_one": {
    null
  }
}
```

With the select in the same spot as the other select columns it just totally breaks and says the column doesn't exist.

I figure it's just an issue of somehow reaching that column via something like `table_one.col_from_other_table` or `table_one->col_from_other_table` but I can't use either of those within the select

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to also select the id or the foreign id depending on the relationship. That's why it's throwing null.

Comment: @IGP May be I misunderstand his question. I think he want get children's columns  to parent's columns.

Comment: @TsaiKoga In that case, he should not be using eloquent relationships. He should be using joins

Comment: @IGP Yes. So I post my answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot select the column in `with()` method **out to the parent's columns**.

Try to use `toSql()` and `getQueryLog()` to see the original SQL:

```php
 $result = Table_one_model::with(
            [
                'Table_two' => function($query) use ($thing_id) {
                    $query->where('thing_id', $thing_id);
                }
            ]
        )
            ->select('col_one', 'col_two');
 print_r($result->toSql()); #=> this will return only one table_one raw sql. So that you cannot select table_two column from table_one.

 \DB::enableQueryLog();
 print_r(\DB::getQueryLog()); #=> this will return two raw sql, the one is table_one, and second is table_two. They are splited.
```

Laravel just hydrate them together.

Check the source code:

```php
    /**
     * Set the relationships that should be eager loaded.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $relations
     * @return $this
     */
    public function with($relations)
    {
        $eagerLoad = $this->parseWithRelations(is_string($relations) ? func_get_args() : $relations);
        $this->eagerLoad = array_merge($this->eagerLoad, $eagerLoad);
        return $this;
    }
```

It return `eagerLoad`, we check the eagerLoad source code:

```php
    /**
     * Eagerly load the relationship on a set of models.
     *
     * @param  array  $models
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  \Closure  $constraints
     * @return array
     */
    protected function eagerLoadRelation(array $models, $name, Closure $constraints)
    {
        // First we will "back up" the existing where conditions on the query so we can
        // add our eager constraints. Then we will merge the wheres that were on the
        // query back to it in order that any where conditions might be specified.
        $relation = $this->getRelation($name);
        $relation->addEagerConstraints($models);
        $constraints($relation);
        // Once we have the results, we just match those back up to their parent models
        // using the relationship instance. Then we just return the finished arrays
        // of models which have been eagerly hydrated and are readied for return.
        return $relation->match(
            $relation->initRelation($models, $name),
            $relation->getEager(), $name
        );
    }
```

It saids that Once we have the results, we just match those back up to their parent models using the relationship instance. Then we just return the finished arrays of models which have been eagerly hydrated and are readied for return.

### Solutions:

So if you want to get the another table columns, 
I think I have two recommend methods:

1. use `with()`, and loop it, get the col from subquery to the parent query. Build the data structure you want
2. try to use `leftjoin` which can select two tables columns, and them group by table_one outside db. Build the data structure you want.

Comment: You **can** use select inside a with closure. You just need to specify the keys as well or Laravel won't be able to load the relationship (resulting in null).

Answer (score 1):

You need to also select the id or the foreign id depending on the relationship. That's why it's throwing null. For example, imagine two models.

```
Parent: id (pk), name, phone, email
Child:  id (pk), name, phone, email, parent_id (fk)
```

Imagine we need to get only the names. It would look like this in Eloquent:

```php
$children = Child::select('children.name'. 'children.parent_id') /* Need to select children.parent_id */
->with(['parent' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('parents.id', 'parents.name');                /* Need to select parents.id */
}])
->get();

$parents = Parent::select('parents.id', 'parents.name')    /* Need to select parents.id */
->with(['children' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('children.name', 'children.parent_id'); /* Need to select children.parent_id */
}])
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 'Table_two' => function($query) use ($thing_id) {
                    $query->where('thing_id', $thing_id);
                }
```

just append your query object  in your sub query condition

```
$query->from('other_table')
    ->selectRaw('col')
    ->where('condition', '>=', val)
    ->where('condition', val);
```

it will generate subquery for you